# How to rename some file of same pattern in shell scripting

Tags: shell

I want to write a code is shell scripting which will rename all the files of extension .txt in a current directory to extension .c .Suppose my current directory contains some 100 .txt file. This number is not fixed.

Comment: Related question: [Better way to rename files based on multiple patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25597051/2654678).

Answer (score 3):

See `man rename`. You can rename multiple files providing regexp substitution.

```
rename 's/\.txt$/.c/' *.txt
```

If you don't have `rename` in you system, you can use find:

```
find . -name '*.txt' | while read FILE; do echo mv "$FILE" "$(echo "$FILE" | sed 's/\.txt$/.c/g')"; done
```

Remove `echo` when you verify it does what you want.

Answer (score 3):

```
for f in *.txt; do echo mv "$f" "${f%.txt}.c"; done
```

Remove "echo" when you're satisfied it's working. See the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) for the meaning of "%" here.

Answer (score 1):

awk can do this trick too:

```
kent$  ls *.txt|awk '{o=$0;gsub(/txt$/,"c"); print "mv "o" "$0;}'|sh
```